# Hibernate: Invalid parameter index

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am trying to update my database table using hibernate but when i try to do this i am getting the following error:

```
10:46:01,034 DEBUG LongType:80 - binding '19991' to parameter: 57
10:46:01,034  INFO LongType:91 - could not bind value '19991' to parameter: 57; Invalid parameter index 57.
10:46:01,049  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:71 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07009
10:46:01,049 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - Invalid parameter index 57.
10:46:01,049 ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener:301 - Could not synchronize database state with session
```

This value that it is trying to insert`19991` is already in the database so i want it to overwrite the value there already, this is the full error

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not update: [com.project.class.dataobject.PSDBusinessAssociate#18962]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2360)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2242)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:709)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
at com.project.class.service.dwr.BusinessAssociateFormService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ff37dc8d.updateBusinessAssociate(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:740)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:744)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:593)
at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:90)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:818)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 57.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.getParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:255)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:326)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setLong(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:509)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:703)
at org.hibernate.type.LongType.set(LongType.java:42)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:83)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:60)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:78)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1932)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2306)
... 57 more
```

This is how i am mapping the document to the database column

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_BusinessAssociate_Document_fitAndProperQuestionnaireId")
@JoinColumn(name = "fitAndProperQuestionnaireId")
@PropertyPresentation(type="documentuploadfield")
private Document fitAndProperQuestionnaire;
```

The naming of the tables and columns are all correct as well, so i don't see what is going wrong! If more code needs to be added just ask and i will add it

**EDIT**

query:

```
update BusinessAssociate set version=?, modifiedBy=?, address1=?, streetTypeId=?, address2=?, address3=?, city=?, stateCode=?, state=?, postCode=?, countryId=?, provinceId=?, islandId=?, percentOwnership=?, comment=?, companyId=?, businessTitleId=?, firstName=?, surname=?, primaryAssociate=?, nationality=?, socialSecurityNumber=?, associateId=?, middleName=?, jobTitle=?, gender=?, previousNames=?, priorAddress1=?, priorStreetTypeId=?, priorAddress2=?, priorAddress3=?, priorCity=?, priorStateCode=?, priorState=?, priorPostCode=?, priorCountryId=?, priorProvinceId=?, priorIslandId=?, workPhoneCountryCode=?, workPhoneCityCode=?, workPhone=?, homePhoneCountryCode=?, homePhoneCityCode=?, homePhone=?, mobilePhoneCountryCode=?, mobilePhoneOperatorCode=?, mobilePhone=?, dateOfBirth=?, cityOfBirth=?, countryOfBirthId=?, proofOfResidentialAddressId=?, addressIdentificationTypeId=?, criminalCheckId=?, fitAndProperQuestionnaireId=? where businessAssociateId=? and version=?
```

Comment: Your query have 57 parameters? Regards

Comment: just counted them there and the update statement only has 54 parameters... i have added the update statement to the question, but would it not pull up the error on 55 and not 57?

Comment: Your query have 56 parameters and you is setting a value in the position 57. This is the problem: could not bind value '19991' to parameter: 57;

Comment: oh right, did not count the where cause, cheers at least now i actually know what the exact problem is :)

Comment: @esmoreno - ya you where right, in the code I had it getting 59 parameters and not 56 which i wanted so it worked then when i removed the extra 3 parameters from the code

Comment: perfect! the question is resolved?

Comment: ya it is resolved, will answer it and put up the solution in a small when i get a chance to

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly something is wrong and you should see add more code so we can try and help. 
In addition, have you set your show_sql parameter in your hibernate.cfg.xml to be true? 
This can help you and see the query that hibernate generates, and maybe (you will have to count though) you will be able to see what's going on 
Not sure though if the query will be present if you have an invalid number of parameters - this is something you need to check. 
In addition, you can change your log4j setting in your application to log as debug all the code under "org.hibernate". 
I think that with better logging you will be able to understand your problem ,and if not - should definitely expose us more code so we can help.

Comment: Ya i have edited my log4j file so that i can see all the sql that hibernate is generating so i can see all the sql statements and i have gone through them already and they are all ok(well one or two of them are in the wrong place and as above im returning 57 when it only needs 54) but the actual SQL code itself is all ok and it is returning all the correct details